# Selecting a radio button by default from a list of radio buttons being fetched dynamically

Tags: angular, dynamic, radio-button, angular-ng-if

Angular 5

I am  *dynamically* populating a radio button group from an array and want to select the first radio button by default. Can I do this by using an `ngIf...then` construct. If so, how?

Also, any other solutions are welcome as well.

**EDIT:** My current implementation that is not working:

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="scheduleEvent" name="schedule" #rg1 ng-checked="">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" style="margin-right:10px;" *ngFor="let schedule of schedules; let idx=index"
                    [value]="schedule" (change)="onSelectionChanged(idx)" *ngIf="idx===0 then selectButtonBlock">
      <ng-template #selectButtonBlock *ng-checked="true"></ng-template>
      {{schedule}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: I could add the error that I'm getting currently for the code I've posted, but I'm not even sure if this implementation is the right way to go - so I don't want it to be the solution under focus

Comment: just when you subscribe to get scheludes, give value to scheleEvent: "this.scheleEvent=this.shedules[0]".

Comment: Can you please provide your array of radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The `scheduleEvent` is bound via `[(ngModel)]`, so you can just change the model, and the view will be updated too. You can select any item by default, for example, like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.scheduleEvent = this.schedules[0];
}
```

And here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxuucw?file=app%2Fradio-ng-model-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. There's an attribute called `checked` and we can set it to true dynamically. Something like this:

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="scheduleEvent" name="schedule" #rg1 ng-checked="">
  <mat-radio-button 
     class="example-radio-button" 
     style="margin-right:10px;" 
     *ngFor="let schedule of schedules; let idx=index"
     [value]="schedule" 
     (change)="onSelectionChanged(idx)" 
     [checked]="idx===0" // Add this line to your code
  >
     {{schedule}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```